# Running unit tests in parallel when using Jmockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, mockito, jmockit

I'm in the process of writing unit test for my project and I'm using TestNG and JMockit for creating test doubles. JMockit looked like a great option at the beginning for its advanced capabilities like mocking static and private methods, but right now, I'm getting some weird issues like ConcurrentModificationException and some other JMockit exceptions.

After doing some research, it looks like JMockit doesn't support concurrent test execution:
http://markmail.org/message/fy4dyegblqsefp7a
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmockit-users/vc-7J3lIrlM

Just for the sake of it, I reimplemented my tests using Mockito and this time they work perfectly fine in parallel, so my question is:
- Have you run into these issues before? How did you solve it?
- Did you stop using JMockit because of this or is there any way of solving it?
- What do you consider most important? Parallel test execution or advanced mocking capabilities?

Thanks everyone

Comment: I have used JMockit but never tried parallel execution with JMockit. How you running tests in parallel? with maven-surefire-plugin?

Comment: See if following link is useful , [ConcurrencyModificationException when using merge](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jmockit-users/thread/jmockit-users/zXqIzuo0TXc/RO6jTUW6bIAJ) . Also, [this](http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r217/trunk/www/changes.html) says that support for running tests in parallel exists since 2009. I think, your test class , config files and execution command needs to be looked at to replicate your scenario as you don't get issues listed in article of your question but different one.

Comment: @Sabir_Khan If you see this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmockit-users/vc-7J3lIrlM , it looks like the parallel execution support is not completely ready.

Comment: yes, I personally asked somebody who extensively works on Jmockit and he also says so ( that it doesn't work well ).

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the answers. Yes, I'm running tests using surefire. When configuring testng.xml to use parallel execution is when I'm getting those errors. The same happens when executing the testng.xml file directly from IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Also, the same issue arise when using TestNGTestRunnerDecorator